# How to add and remove class based on the array values

Tags: jquery

I have got a div as shown below

```
<div class="addonsQtyWrap">
      <ul>
         <li data-vendoritemid="844" data-tabid="1" class="tabclcik active">Qty-1</li>
         <li data-vendoritemid="844" data-tabid="2" class="tabclcik active">Qty-2</li>
         <li data-vendoritemid="844" data-tabid="3" class="tabclcik">Qty-3</li>
         <li data-vendoritemid="844" data-tabid="4" class="tabclcik active">Qty-4</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
```

as you see , some of them above  might  have class **active** and some of them don't have .

My requirement is that , i need to add class **active** to only those which are part of an **array** and remove class **active** which are not present in the **array**

I tried this way

```
 var activequantities  = ["1","4"];

for(var i=0;i<activequantities.length;i++)
{
var tabnumber = activequantities[i];
$("#popupinner844").find('.tabclcik[data-tabid="' + tabnumber + '"]').addClass('active');    
}
```

With the sample data (array of 1 and 4 ) given  my requirement is that , i need to add the class active only to the 1 and 4 , at the same time remove the class active on 2 and 3 .

But i couldn't able to remove class active which are not part of an array

could you please let me know how to achieve this .

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/52/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for your javascript:

```
 var activequantities  = ["1", "4"];

 // remove all occurrences of active class
 $("#popupinner844 .tabclcik").removeClass('active');

 // selectively add active class back according to array contents above
 for(var i=0;i<activequantities.length;i++) {
   var tabnumber = activequantities[i];
   $("#popupinner844").find("[data-tabid='" + tabnumber + "']").addClass('active');    
}
```

Comment: As i am new to jquery , This one seems perfect for me , i can have complete control with this code .

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
var activequantities = ["1","4"];
$("li.tabclcik").removeClass('active').filter(function () {
    return $.inArray($(this).data('tabid').toString(), activequantities) > -1
}).addClass('active');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cod7ceho/57/)**

You select the list items, remove the class from all of them, then filter by checking whether their data attribute occurs in your array, and add the active class only to those elements.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - I don't think the looping would be reduced by that. I'm also not sure toggleClass would work using the same function.

Answer (score 1):

The following function loops through through all your `<li>` elements, then checks the `data-tabid` attribute against the array you defined. If the attribute is in the array then add the class, otherwise remove the class.

You can run the snippet for a working example.

```js
$(function() {
  var activequantities  = ["1","4"];

  $(".addonsQtyWrap li").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var dataTabId = $this.attr("data-tabid");
    if (activequantities.indexOf(dataTabId) < 0)
      $this.removeClass("active");
    else
      $this.addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.active { background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="addonsQtyWrap">
      <ul>
         <li data-vendoritemid="844" data-tabid="1" class="tabclcik active">Qty-1</li>
         <li data-vendoritemid="844" data-tabid="2" class="tabclcik active">Qty-2</li>
         <li data-vendoritemid="844" data-tabid="3" class="tabclcik">Qty-3</li>
         <li data-vendoritemid="844" data-tabid="4" class="tabclcik active">Qty-4</li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: plus one for $()() and $this ref save :)

Comment: Thank you very much This one looks clean .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `each()` method and then check `indexOf()` the array

```
var activequantities  = ["1","4"];

$("ul li").each(function(){
if(activequantities.indexOf($(this).data("tabid").toString())!=-1){
$(this).addClass("active");
}
else
$(this).removeClass("active");

})
```

**Working Demo:**

```js
var activequantities  = ["1","4"];
$("ul li").each(function(){
   console.log(activequantities.indexOf($(this).data("tabid")))
if(activequantities.indexOf($(this).data("tabid").toString())==-1){
   $(this).removeClass("active");
}
 else
   $(this).addClass("active");

})
```

```css
.active { color: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="addonsQtyWrap">
      <ul>
         <li data-vendoritemid="844" data-tabid="1" class="tabclcik active">Qty-1</li>
         <li data-vendoritemid="844" data-tabid="2" class="tabclcik active">Qty-2</li>
         <li data-vendoritemid="844" data-tabid="3" class="tabclcik">Qty-3</li>
         <li data-vendoritemid="844" data-tabid="4" class="tabclcik active">Qty-4</li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: 20seconds.toString();  ...  @dave :)